# How do I turn this Json file into an int array?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a program that calculates and returns the largest number inside of an array of integers.

I know how to return the largest number if the array is an int[].
But I am not sure how to return the largest number from a json file.
The json file has to be entered as an argument inside of Main().

So the point is that when I run the application the program should return the number 7 when the json file is the argument inside of static void Main(string[] args).

Surely there is some command like dotnet run "data.json" if I want to run the json file as an argument from the class Program?

The program consist of 3 files.
The main program file.
The class Max, with the methods returnMax and showResult.
And of course the json file.

I have read the newtonsoft documentation but haven't found anything valuable to solve this problem.

Could someone help me out?

The main Program code:

```
namespace json
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      // So the jason.file should be put as an argument inside of
      // the static void Main(string[] args).
      // And a 7 should be returned.
      string json = File.ReadAllText(args);
      int[] numbers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int[]>(json);

      Console.WriteLine(Max.showResult(numbers));
    }
  }
}
```

The Max code:

```
namespace json
{
  public class Max
  {

    public static dynamic showResult(int[] source)
    { 
      return $"The largest number is: {returnMax(numbers)}";
    }
    public static int returnMax(int[] source)
    {

      int largestNumber = source.Max();
      return largestNumber;

    }
  }
}
```

The data.json file:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
```

So I expect Console.WriteLine(Max.showResult(source)) to return 7 when I have the json file as an argument inside of `static void Main(string[] args)`.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Loading the file to a string, or deserializing that string as an `int[]`?

Comment: Well, you might believe you have read theJson.NET documentation, but it seems you somehow managed to entirely miss the samples section, which contains an example that [shows how you might deserialize a string representing Json array data](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeCollection.htm) with elements of some type into a List<SomeType>.

Comment: the problem is that I have to make it so,
`string json = File.ReadAllText(args);
int[] numbers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int[]>(json);`
works.

Comment: `args` is a string array. You cannot use `args` as a parameter for `File.ReadAllText`, because File.ReadAllText expects a string (not a string array!!!) that contains the path to the file being read. Look up the documentation about the purpose of the `args` argument of the Main method is and why it is a string array. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/command-line-arguments)

Comment: So I need to run the static void Main(string[] data.json) from the console and get 7 back.

Comment: `File.ReadAllText(args)` will never work, as `File.ReadAllText` takes a *single* string - but `File.ReadAllText(args[0])` should work. I'd strongly recommend learning about and following .NET naming conventions, and avoiding dynamic typing unless you really need it.

Comment: Isn't it an argument like every other argument? I do understand what you wrote, but I don't understand how to get around it.

Comment: Look up the documentation explaining the purpose of the args argument for the Main method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/command-line-arguments. Then it should become clearer to you how you can correctly use `args` in the Main methods of your programming projects...

Answer (score 1):

If you are still in trouble I managed a solution and it's working (command line gives me 7 as biggest number).
Here is what I've done: 
1) I modified the json file:

```
{
  "numbers": [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
}
```

I made this change because it is important to have a class that is similar to json 
file, otherwise Jsondeserializer won't work (this is what I've learned), so this is the corresponding class where I'll store json data:

```
namespace MaxNumberJson
{
    class JsonDeserializer
    {
    public List<int> numbers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

2) Then, because of using List<> I modified your methods in this way (I basically changed the parameters):

```
class MaxNumber
    {
        public string showResult(List<int> source)
        {
            return $"The largest number is: {returnMax(source)}";
        }
        public static int returnMax(List<int> source)
        {

            int largestNumber = source.Max();
            return largestNumber;

        }
    }
```

3) Finally I wrote some code on main.cs:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            JsonDeserializer jsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
            MaxNumber maxNumber = new MaxNumber();
            string json = File.ReadAllText(args[0]);
            jsonDeserializer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonDeserializer>(json);

            Console.WriteLine(maxNumber.showResult(jsonDeserializer.numbers));
        }
    }
```

The first class (JsonDeserializer) is the class i created just to store json data form file; after that i put the content of the file passed by command line in a string and the I used the newtonsoft library and finally printed the output; Hope this could help!

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention that I passed the complete path of the file as argument.
Moreover, I passed the path of the file as argument in this way:
Right click on the project and the on Properties>Debug and then pass the complete path